# Where can the documentation for python-Levenshtein be found online?

Tags: python, documentation, levenshtein-distance

I've found a great python library implementing Levenshtein functions (distance, ratio, etc.) at http://code.google.com/p/pylevenshtein/ but the project seems inactive and the documentation is nowhere to be found. 
I was wondering if anyone knows better than me and can point me to the documentation.

Comment: It looks like the author even included a gendoc.sh that would generate documentation.txt from a website for you, but that website is now done. I assume the official documentation no longer exists where the author means it to.

Comment: @sihrc, that URL refers to a *tool* used to generate the documentation.  It's not available at that URL anymore but you can [still find it elsewhere](http://sources.gentoo.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/gentoo-x86/dev-python/python-levenshtein/files/genextdoc.py?revision=1.1.1.1&content-type=text%2Fplain).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You won't have to generate the docs yourself. There's an online copy of the original Python Levenshtein API: http://www.coli.uni-saarland.de/courses/LT1/2011/slides/Python-Levenshtein.html

Comment: The official documentation now links here: https://rawgit.com/ztane/python-Levenshtein/master/docs/Levenshtein.html

Answer (score 51):

Here is an example:

```
# install with: pip install python-Levenshtein

from Levenshtein import distance
edit_dist = distance("ah", "aho")
```

Comment: They should add these 2 lines on their PyPI page, it's worth a thousand words.

Comment: @SergeMosin here we go https://github.com/ztane/python-Levenshtein/pull/39

Answer (score 2):

Follow instructions at the updated version:
https://github.com/joncasdam/python-Levenshtein

To get a generated documentation. This was updated 3 months back.

Answer (score 1):

download it from that google repo

extract it

download http://kambing.ui.ac.id/gentoo-portage/dev-python/python-levenshtein/files/genextdoc.py to the same folder where you extracted

double click on gendoc.sh

you should now see a levenstein.html which is the documentation