# regex match item in python Counter

Tags: python, regex, list, counter

I have this sample code for python [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html).

```
from collections import Counter

lst = ['item', 'itemm', 'iitem', 'foo', 'bar'] 
c = Counter(lst) 
Counter({'bar': 1, 'foo': 1, 'iitem': 1, 'item': 1, 'itemm': 1})
```

If I do `c['item']` I get `1`, but I want to get `3` due to the typos in the list.

I tried the following, it doesn't give me `3` but I still work with it:

```
import re

for word in lst:
    if re.search('item',word):
        print(word,c[word])

item 1
itemm 1
iitem 1
```

Is there a more efficent way to do it without looping through list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use list_comprehension along with `sum`

```
>>> d = {'bar': 1, 'foo': 1, 'iitem': 1, 'item': 1, 'itemm': 1}
>>> sum([d[i] for i in d.keys() if re.search(r'item', i)])
3
```

or

Without regex,

```
>>> sum([d[i] for i in d.keys() if 'item' in  i])
3
```

Comment: Thank you, the one without regex is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give a few more details of solving [an approximate matching of strings](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/fuzzy-string-python) (this is the underlying problem here).

Orthographical errors are can be matched using edit distance check (or so called [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) metric). It can be calculated using [`python-Levenshtein`](https://pypi.org/project/python-Levenshtein/) package:

```
from Levenshtein import distance
edit_dist = distance("ah", "aho")
```

The example is taken from [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134437/where-can-the-documentation-for-python-levenshtein-be-found-online) on SO referring to this particular module.

Another reference for [fuzzy string matching in Python](https://stackabuse.com/levenshtein-distance-and-text-similarity-in-python/).