# Regular Expression to find Name from Email address

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

In python, I am trying to create an algorithm that will use characters from an email address and search the page to calculate the likelihood the string is the actual name of the person.  I wrote a regex expression to grab all emails on a page, but then I want to write another to try and find the persons name from the email (since it is a subset or some characters of the name make it up).

I am using:

```
 self.reEmail = re.compile(r"\b(?!(?:.\B)*(.)(?:\B.)*\1)[char]+\b", re.IGNORECASE)
```

However this is giving me all single characters.

email: bjoel@email.edu

Name : Billy Joel  - is what I want to scrape.

However it is not always the first letter of the email is the first name...

Comment: I am not trying to validate an email address, I want to apply an algo like difflib or levenshtein to grab the name related to the email address.. However I tried both and difflib depends on character order along with levenshtein which will calculate distance away.

Comment: @Jan: maybe a little too quick! Ok, don't close - don't close...

Comment: Use [`\b(\S+@\S+)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/vF9iZ2/1) and have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134437/where-can-the-documentation-for-python-levenshtein-be-found-online

Comment: @Jan I used that regex to get all the emails, but now I want to search the DOM again and try and find that persons name that corresponds to the email.  That regex only provides the emails which I already have.

Comment: I hope that it's not for spam purposes. I don't think that Billy Joel would appreciate this.

Comment: There is no regular expression that can match `Billy Joel` from `bjoel@email.edu` simply because the given name is not in there completely. But that's only one of the many problems you are facing. Solving all would be far too broad for SO.

Comment: It is a duplicate because once you parse it, you will have the real name in the correctly notated capture buffers from the subexpression matches.